# macbook mid 2010 13" won't recognise ssd crucial mx200 HD 500gb placed in the optical drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd, upgrade

I have a macbook pro 13" mid 2009 2,26GHz with HDD 160gb. I recently replaced my optical drive with a crucial SSD 240GB and it works really good and it was quite an easy process. Now i am trying to do the same to a friends Macbook pro 13" mid 2010 with a crucial MX200 SSD 500gb, only now 
it is not recognisable at all by the MBP.

- both sata drives on MBP 2010 are on 3gb/s speeds while the ssd is 6gb/s!
- Both macbook run el capitan

I tried disk utilities , i tried restarting with cmd + R and again is not there. I also replaced my friends sata cable with mine (which works fine) and still nothing. I am looking to several articles over the net and the most hopeful case is to replace the sata cable from the ssd to the board. If thats the case i will not have to return the item or lose my money but just buy a new cable.

Basically, do some SATA cables prevent negotiation to 6Gbps or is the 3 Gbps something to ignore and instead focus on maybe the adaptor i got to fit in the new ssd might be broken somewhere in the connection?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware shopping questions are off topic. If you want to remove the "where do I get cable X" and make it about how to learn what the specifications needed - we can easily reopen it. That way anyone can shop for the price of parts that meet the specifications.

Comment: Also - try to isolate to one question. Once you get one answer - asking another single question works best. As you see - someone chose to answer one of your many questions, and your comment shows you had a follow on one.

Comment: Sorry for that.. The shopping part is the last i care about..I am not fully familiar with how this forum works as i'm new here..i re-edited

Comment: good work Nash - I made a further edit to call out the clear question at the end. Putting the edits / details on the setup up above. Let's see if this helps get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to put the SuperDrive back, and then seeing if the SATA cable for that works, if it does, you can switch the HDD for the SSD to check if it's faulty.

Also - there are inexpensive power supply / USB data connection kits so you could get one of those and test the bracket you purchased external to either MacBook and see if everything works over USB first.

- the inexpensive self powered ones are fine in most cases
- if you're wanting something to be sure you have a good part, consider getting one with a power supply. (or three since they are so cheap and as you know - sometimes a new part could be bad so having spares to test helps greatly). [https://www.amazon.com/SANOXY-A12940-Drive-Adapter-Converter/dp/B001OORMVQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OORMVQ)

I wouldn't worry about a link negotiation between 3 Gbps or 6 Gbps - either will result in things working and even in the most stringent benchmark - it's almost never you are seeing more than 3 Gbps on a sata link so in practice you see no benefit from that - certainly not a cause for a drive not showing up entirely.

Comment: i switched the sata cable from my MBP 2009 that works perfect with the new SSD and still nothing..

Comment: That is a great step further..thanks a lot.. i will be back after testing everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Back after more than a month! First of all thanks for your suggestions. So i got the necessary data cables , i formatted externally the old hard drive (so there wasn't any problem with the HDD) and waited for the new bracket to arrive so i can replace it with the new-broken one and everything works fine! Only issue i'm facing now is the new 16GB RAM (2x4gb) i got for the macbook pro 7.1 (mid-2010 , 13") won't boot the MBP but i found out my slot speed is 8500 and the RAM is 10600 so i re-order a slower version and now waiting (i just mention that in case someone faces same issue / sorry if its irrelevant to the post). 
Again thanks a lot for the help..

ps. the data cables i got allowed me to use 2 old HDDs from a dead lap top i had for years , as external back up and storage hard disks (saved a lot of money and the environment) !